# Bootstrap: How to make a "rowspan" with floating elements?

Tags: html, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert a table view into a floating view. It has two columns, the first column should have one row, the second column has two rows. I want the row of the first column to stretch out, so that it spans over the two rows of the second column.

Currently my HTML is this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span1" style="background-color: #FF0000">
    First column with single row goes here
</div>
<div class="span11">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" style="background-color: #00FF00"> 
            First row of second column goes here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" style="background-color: #0000FF">
            Second row of second column goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i have a problem: The single-rowed column does not span over both rows of the second column. It has the same height as the first row, and has a whitespace below it with the same height as the the second row.

How am i supposed to stretch this cell over both rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way, using the concept of tables/rows to apply to div containers.  They don't really work like that.

You could do this with CSS.

Add float:left; to all your div containers or classes.

Add `margin-left:100px;` to your styles that you want in 'column 2'.  This will push them away from the first column.

Add `height:100px;` to your left column div to give it a fixed height.

You could dial all this in like that.

Also, you may be using the class 'row' incorrectly, since it's wrapping around the entire group, but it's also the class applied to the 2nd row.  You may want to make these different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work as you want:

```
<div style="background-color: #FF0000">
  First column with single row goes here
</div>
<div style="background-color: #00FF00; width:50%; float:left;"> 
  First row of second column goes here
</div>
<div style="background-color: #0000FF; width:50%; float:left;">
  Second row of second column goes here
</div>
```

I don't know what code you have in your CSS classes, so I removed them in my answer. You may have to modify that code to get it to work.

I set the width of the columns to 50 %. If you want some other widths, change these values. Just make sure the sum is 100.

I also removed some HTML code I don't think is needed. At least as far as I understand your question.